# Multiple commands within ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm having trouble running multiple commands within a Scriptblock parameter.  All documentation points towards using a semicolon for separation between cmdlets.  Using the same methodology of separating cmdlets via a semicolon works on my local machine, but not on a remote machine through invoke-command.

For example, the below code will only return the result of `Get-Service`, and not `Get-Process`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName cas-bkupexec -ScriptBlock { Get-Service;  Get-Process }
```

How can I achieve the desired result of both commands successfully running and receive the output of each?

Comment: It returns the result of both for me, one after the other. Can you describe exactly your environment and test, what you expect and what you get?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'm running this particular invoke-command against a Windows Server 2003 box.  I'm expecting to get both the results of get-service, and then get-process.  However, I only receive the results of Get-Service.  It appears as though it's skipping get-process.

Comment: @PetSerAl I tried that and still only receive the output of Get-Service on the remote machine.

Comment: What is PowerShell version on client and on server?

Comment: @PetSerAl Version 5 on client, 2 on remote machine.  Perhaps some sort of compatibility issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this.. it only returns the first statement. It's not the semicolon, it does the same thing if you use line breaks.

These options work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-Service)
    Get-Process
}
```

Or this curiously:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock {
    & { 
        Get-Service
        Get-Process
    }
}
```

Since wrapping one of them in `( )` works I feel like this must be some quirk of the pipeline but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what it's doing yet.

#### Update:

After reading your comment that your source machine was running v5 and the remote v2, I realized that my testing did the same.

When I remoted from the v5 into itself, the issue disappeared.

Remoting from:

```
v2 -> v5: no issue
v2 -> itself: no issue
v2 -> other v2: no issue
v3 -> v2: no issue
v3 -> v5: no issue
v3 -> itself: no issue
v4 -> v2: no issue
v4 -> v3: no issue
v4 -> itself: no issue
v4 -> v5: no issue
```

Not every combination here, but it seems like it really may be a bug from v5 to v2.

Comment: I'll use this as a workaround in the meantime.  Thanks.  Would still love to see why the expected behavior of command separation via semicolon isn't working though.  Or an explanation as to why..

Comment: Could this be another victim of the formatting engine formatting all output for the first thing it gets (`Get-Service`), and since `Get-Process` has different output it ignores it? Then wrapping the first one outputs that as a separate process, so the formatting engine has a degree of separation and outputs correctly? Just a guess, but it kind of makes sense to me.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that's what I initially thought too, so I captured the output in a variable, checked the count, checked the first and last element, make sure it wasn't an array of arrays, etc. The output really wasn't there. :(

Answer (score 3):

You could try to separate them by a comma which would make the results an array that you could then look at by each index.

```
$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName cas-bkupexec -ScriptBlock { (Get-Service), (Get-Process) }

#Services
$Results[0]

#Processes
$Results[1]
```

Comment: Yes this works, however I'm still confused as to why I can't simply use the semicolon to separate the two Cmdlets within the Scriptblock.  Is using a semicolon to separate commands invalid syntax for the -Scriptblock parameter?

Comment: Yea, that is odd. Might be something with the pipeline as briantist pointed out. If you run it like this, it works as expected: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName J23 -ScriptBlock {$a = Get-Process;$b = Get-Service;$a;$b}`. The moment you add any command that sends data to the pipeline such as Write-Output, it will only display the first item.

Comment: @AlexEdwards your syntax is perfectly valid; this looks to be a bug between v5 and v2, see the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The options mentioned above as answer didn't work for me. But, I worked by using below command.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock {(Get-Service), (Get-Process)}
```

Comment: parenthesis worked for me too. Example below where I wanted to print the machine named followed by the results of a command, in this case get the version of chrome on a machine:
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyMachine -ScriptBlock {(hostname),$(Get-Package -Name "Google Chrome").Version}`